# Two end points work without configuration - showing same view

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot (2.5.6)'s Controller like this:

```
@Controller
public class WebController {
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String indexPage () {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And when I hit these two URLs:

```
http://localhost:8080/index
http://localhost:8080
```

Same Thymeleaf view `index.html` is served. To my understanding on hitting `http://localhost:8080` I should get - `Whitelabel Error Page`.

In the past I have used something like this `@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/index" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)` extensively. What I am missing/overlooking here?

Comment: How do you deploy your application? This looks like the welcome page mechanism that can be defined in `web.xml` and will be honored by an external servlet container.

Comment: Havn't deployed it anywhere yet. Still in STS only. Have only two classes. Controller and SBApplication. Pure vanilla. No additional code is written yet.

Comment: Spring Boot adds a `WelcomePageHandlerMapping` to mimic the welcome page behavior and thus `/` and `/index` will yield the same result if they point to the same page.

Comment: @M.Deinum Why don't you add the comment as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot, through [auto-configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/f1991d8d80d72d3150256e53e0f6ffd8bcd379e2/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L452), will add a [`WelcomePageHandlerMapping`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WelcomePageHandlerMapping.java). The `WelcomePageHandlerMapping` will mimic the behavior of the welcome-page support in Servlet containers like Tomcat.

By default it will try to locate an `index.html` in either the `static` or `template` directory and, if needed, use the available templating framework to render this page.

Comment: Hmm. I had my index.html in static folder.

Comment: Regardless without this handler that wouldn't have worked without the full path.