# How to access HTML files **through a controller** in Spring boot without a template engine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller

So I have been trying hard to get a simple app to run with populating an HTML file through a controller without using a template engine.

I thought I would take some time to post about my findings related to the subject above. See answer below

Soo the question here is How to access HTML files **through a controller** in Spring boot without a template engine?

Comment: `/static` is for static files and not related to Thymeleaf. Also you don't need a controller but you are better of registering a view controller through a `WebMvcConfigurer`. Also for `index` this isn't needed as that is already resolved by Spring Boot by default (if you have an up to date version).

Comment: Agreed, It is already handled through Spring boot BUT it is not by default accessible through a controller. If I explicitly type in the html file name in my url header it will of course populate but the goal is to produce the file when "/" was being requested.

Comment: For `/` this is already enabled by default (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70000437/2696260) so you shouldn't even need it (unless you disabled auto-configuration),

Comment: Agreed. It works by default but only works if you are using index.html....if you wanted to use a controller to route to another static file.....perhaps extra.html you will need a controller to route to the specific file in the static folder

Comment: No you don't need a controller you can simply use a the `addViewControllers` method of the `WebMvcConfigurer` to add those. No need to write a full fledge controller for that. Next to that your answer/question states that you need this for `/` to resolve an index, which isn't true as that works by default.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a very simplistic answer to a simple issue, this is not meant to scale and does not take into account the entirety of your project**

Please keep in mind this is not the norm in a business environment but it was really bothering me how I cannot get a simple HTML to populate from a controller without using a template engine. I got it to work with thymeleaf dependency but I wanted to just get it to work as bare bones as possible. I read a lot of posts with ViewResolver Config classes or things a like but nothing worked. It would conflict with the internal resolvers of Spring boot.

Simple answer is once spring boot is initialized...all your static files must be in `resources/static/`

Templates folder is specific to use for Thymeleaf, based on my findings and it wont work if you just put it in the resource folders.

With your files in `resources/static/` you can access it by going to **localhost:8080/yourfilename.html**

But if you want to access it through a controller you create a controller with the following:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getIndex(){
        return " index.html";
    }
}
```

If you want to remove the `.html` in your return value then you must add the following to your application.properties file

`spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html`

Then you can use the following

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getIndex(){
        return " index";
    }
}
```

Once again this is a simple research I did on my own just to get it to work.